# Omnet++ throwing an error in module, but I cant find it

Tags: omnet++

I am running a simulation to compare two mobile routing protocols, AODV and DSDV. When I run the simulation for AODV I get no errors, but when I run it for DSDV I get error in module.

I have posted the config.

It is the same NED file and INI file for both simulations.
Thanks.

```
[General]
  network = Net80211_DSR

  

tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins


sim-time-limit = 60s # set simulation time in second.
seed-0-mt = 5 # define numbers of seeds for results accuracy.


*.numFixHosts = 1
  

*.numHosts = 24

**.throughput.scalar-recording = true
**.jitter.scalar-recording = true
**.manetRouting.scalar-recording = true 
**.udpApp*.vector-recording = false 
**.vector-recording = false 
**.scalar-recording = false 

**.drawCoverage=false
**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 1000m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 1000m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m

**.host*.mobilityType = "RandomWPMobility"
**.host*.mobility.initFromDisplayString = false
**.host*.mobility.speed = 4mps

**.host[*].numUdpApps = 1
**.host[*].udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicBurst"
**.udpApp[0].localPort = 100
**.udpApp[0].destPort = 100
**.udpApp[0].messageLength = 512B
**.udpApp[0].sendInterval = 0.5s
**.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "fixhost[0]"

**.udpApp[0].chooseDestAddrMode = "perBurst"
**.udpApp[0].burstDuration = 100s
**.udpApp[0].sleepDuration = 1s
**.udpApp[0].startTime = 1s
**.udpApp[0].delayLimit = 2s
**.udpApp[0].destAddrRNG = 0

**.fixhost[0].udpApp[*].typename = "UDPSink"
**.fixhost[0].numUdpApps = 1
**.fixhost[0].udpApp[0].localPort = 100

**.wlan*.bitrate = 54Mbps
**.wlan*.typename="Ieee80211Nic"
**.wlan*.opMode="g"
**.wlan*.mac.EDCA = false
**.wlan*.mgmt.frameCapacity = 10
**.wlan*.mac.maxQueueSize = 14
**.wlan*.mac.rtsThresholdBytes = 3000B
**.wlan*.mac.basicBitrate = 6Mbps  # 24Mbps
**.wlan*.mac.retryLimit = 7
**.wlan*.mac.cwMinData = 31 # 
**.wlan*.mac.cwMaxData = 31# 

*.channelControl.pMax = 2.0mW
**.wlan*.radio.transmitterPower=2.0mW
**.wlan*.radio.sensitivity=-90dBm
**.wlan*.radio.berTableFile="per_table_80211g_Trivellato.dat"
**.broadcastDelay=uniform(0s,0.005s)
  
[Config AODV]
**.routingProtocol="AODVUU"
**.numHosts = ${Density=5,10,15,20,25,30}

[Config DSDV]
**.routingProtocol="DSDV_2"
**.numHosts = ${Density=5,10,15,20,25,30}
```

NED.FILE

```
package inet.examples.CSN09114.Lab5_AODV_DSDV;

import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.util.ThruputMeteringChannel;
import inet.world.radio.ChannelControl;
//
// Example network for testing aodv routing. Contains
// fixed and mobile nodes. Mobile nodes are not moving,
// but are scattered randomly on the playground.
//
network Net80211_DSR
{
  parameters:
                @display("bgi=background/green,s");
            int numHosts;
            int numFixHosts;
          submodules:
                 fixhost[numFixHosts]: AdhocHost {
                     parameters:
                    @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");
                 }
            host[numHosts]: AdhocHost {
                 parameters:
                 @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");

                }
                channelControl: ChannelControl {
                parameters:
                  @display("p=50,36;i=misc/sun");
 }
                configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
                    parameters:
                    config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.0.0'/><interface fixhosts='0' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.0.0'/></config>");
                            @display("p=733,23;i=block/cogwheel_s");
              }
    
                connections allowunconnected:
}
```

This is the error:

> OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2013 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
> Version: 4.4.1, build: 140307-1086eab, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
> See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
> Setting up Cmdenv...
> Loading NED files from ../../../RPL: 0
> Loading NED files from ../..:
> 211 Loading NED files from ../../../src: 438
>
> Preparing for running configuration DSDV, run #5... Scenario:
> $Density=30, $repetition=0 Assigned
> runID=DSDV-5-20210228-09:23:06-4386 Setting up network
> `Net80211_DSR'... Initializing...
>
> RUNTIME ERROR. A cRuntimeError exception is about to be thrown, and
> you requested (by setting debug-on-errors=true in the ini file) that
> errors abort execution and break into the debugger.
>
> You should now probably be running the simulation under gdb or another
> debugger. The simulation kernel will now raise a SIGABRT signal which
> will get you into the debugger. If you are not running under a
> debugger, you can still use the core dump for post-mortem debugging.
> Once in the debugger, view the call stack (in gdb: "bt" command) to
> see the context of the runtime error.
>
> **<!> Error in module (DSDV_2) Net80211_DSR.fixhost[0].manetrouting (id=44) during network initialization: RNG index 1 is out of range
> (num-rngs=1, check the configuration).**
>
> TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true
> configuration option. Is your debugger ready?
>
> Simulation terminated with exit code: 133 Working directory:
> /home/napier/omnetpp-4.4.1/samples/inetmanet-2.0/examples/CSN09114/Lab5_AODV_DSDV
> Command line: opp_run -r 5 -u Cmdenv -c DSDV -n
> ../../../RPL:../..:../../../src -l ../../../src/inet
> --record-eventlog=false --debug-on-errors=true omnetpp.ini
>
> Environment variables:
> PATH=/home/napier/omnetpp-4.4.1/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
> OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/napier/omnetpp-4.4.1/images
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/napier/omnetpp-4.4.1/lib::/home/napier/omnetpp-4.4.1/samples/inetmanet-2.0/src: